# apply shadow to outermost section?

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply the shadow property in CSS to an outer div? The way I have my stuff organized is like this:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

And i'd like to do something like:

```
#outer{
display:block;
width: 825px;
height 300px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #319a00;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #319a00;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #319a00;
}
```

But it creates a shadow with no height. Any ideas?

Comment: you forgot the colon (:) with `height` in CSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you have missed adding a colon after `height` in your CSS :) I don't think there's anything stranger to it than that.